# Saving ArrayList Data after switching Activities

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have two ArrayLists in two Activities. The first ArrayList contains about 1000 Items (saved in a JSON file) and the second ArrayList contains 0 Items.

It is possible to add 1 Item to ArrayList2 with "onClick"

But when I close the App the Activities wont save.

How can I save these changes?

1.MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static ArrayList<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList();
public class ObjList{
    public ArrayList<String> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_view);
    recipeList = Recipe.getRecipesFromFile("recipes.json", this);
    String[] listItems = new String[recipeList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < recipeList.size(); i++) {
        Recipe recipe = recipeList.get(i);
        listItems[i] = recipe.title;
    }


    final RecipeAdapter adapter = new RecipeAdapter(this, recipeList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    final Context context = this;
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Recipe selectedRecipe = recipeList.get(position);
            recipeList.remove(selectedRecipe);
            recipeList2.add(selectedRecipe);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    });
};
public void test_onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private ListView mListView;
}
```

2.Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 static ArrayList<Recipe> recipeList2 = new ArrayList<>();


   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView mListView;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.testlist2);
    final RecipeAdapter adapter = new RecipeAdapter (this, recipeList2);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    final Context context = this;
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Recipe selectedRecipe = recipeList2.get(position);
            recipeList2.remove(selectedRecipe);
            recipeList.add(selectedRecipe);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }});}
public void test2_onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Recipe.class:

```
  public static ArrayList<Recipe> getRecipesFromFile(String filename, Context context){
final ArrayList<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();


try {
  // Load data
  String jsonString = loadJsonFromAsset("recipes.json", context);
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  JSONArray recipes = json.getJSONArray("recipes");

  // Get Recipe objects from data
  for(int i = 0; i < recipes.length(); i++){
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

    recipe.title = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");


    recipeList.add(recipe);
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

return recipeList;  }
  private static String loadJsonFromAsset(String filename, Context context) {
String json = null;

try {
  InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename);
  int size = is.available();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
  is.read(buffer);
  is.close();
  json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
}
catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
  return null;
}

return json;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that attempts to save the list... Why did you think it would save? Try writing back to a file

Comment: Yea i know because i dont know how the save my List

Comment: Open a `File` object on disk, and write to it

Answer (score 0):

If you close app, unsaved data is removed. Take a look on [android activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). When app is closed, `onDestroy()` is called.  You should override onDestroy() method in activity, which is supposed to save changes.